# remove books from daughters iPad with a kindle app

Tags: kindle

I loaded the Kindle App onto my daughter's iPad. Her kindle app is synced to my Amazon account. I want to remove the books that she will likely have no interest and only keep the books I want her to read.

Is there a way to remove the books without actually deleting from my account?